# possible woocommce bug keep showing "total_sales" in metabox "custom field" add/edit product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, storefront, woocommerce-theming

As shown in the edit/add product page, this item "total_sales" always show up in the default metabox "custom field".
It's not doing any harm yet but it's annoying. 
However, someone might edit the total sales number by accident and would cause problems.

I am writing a child theme from storeFront.
Is this a bug in woocommerce or did I accidentally changed something somewhere that causes this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by default. If you think this is a bug then you can always open a thread on https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues

> EDIT

[Custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) or post meta entries can be hidden from the by default in Wordpress available »Custom Fields«-Metabox by prefixing them with a underscore - `_` - as noted [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta#Hidden_Custom_Fields).

If you want to hide the field you can use this piece of code that i wrote for you

```php
function filter_is_protected_meta( $protected, $meta_key, $meta_type ) {    
    if ( $meta_key == 'total_sales' ) {
        $protected = true;
    }

    return $protected; 
}
add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', 'filter_is_protected_meta', 10, 3 );
```